# Any rules for reporting posts that belong on forked sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, migration

What are the rules for reporting posts that belong on other sites (forked of Stack Overflow)?

I tried to go through the LaTeX questions and reported those that were absolutely clearly only about LaTeX (no programming, etc...). But 50% of these reports were ignored/refused (can't see the resolution).

So what are the rules for reporting?

Specifically:

- old posts
- posts with positive rating
- posts with multiple answers
- posts with accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, it depends on the moderator who handles the flag.  No, to truly be honest--it depends on the whim of the moderator at the time he/she sees the flag who decides to handle the flag.

There are no hard rules about this.  It is all subjective.  I'd say the one thing you can be guaranteed of is that questions with an accepted answer or that are older than a year won't get migrated.

If a question has an accepted answer, there is pretty much no point in migrating it.  Usually, in these cases, it is acceptable to flag as off-topic (if you cannot vote to do so).  The question can be closed as such.

Old questions are also generally not worth migrating.  If the question is from ought-nine or before, I'd suggest you vote to close/flag as off-topic, and edit the question to add the following to the top:

> This question exists because it has
>   historical significance, but it is not
>   considered a good, on-topic question
>   for this site, so please do not use it
>   as evidence that you can ask similar
>   questions here.
>
> More info: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Hmm, I would consider migrating old answered questions very sensible, since that would make them searchable on the new site.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Hmmm, having a hard time finding the relevant posts, but it is the generally accepted opinion that migrating old questions isn't something that should be done on a regular basis... But, like most things, there isn't a definitive rule on the subject.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - the prime motivation for migrating a question should be to enable it to get better answers. The "benefit" of having it on a more appropriate site is secondary. If the question is old or has an accepted answer then the prime motivation is gone and the secondary one is pretty weak.

Comment: @Will Checkout this one (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193298/best-practices-in-latex

Comment: @ChrisF I see one more motivation. Routing to users to the correct site. Asking (non-programming) Latex questions on Stackoverflow is offtopic, but search will return Latex questions.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Ugh, "But what about this question!" Its the bane of moderator's lives.  1.5 *million* questions.  I usually leave questions like this (i.e., not horrible, but probably should be dealt with) to the community.

Comment: @Will Sorry I'm confused. I posted the question link as a reaction to your "having hard time finding relevant posts" comment. And I'm sure, that you don't get millions of reports.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I know; don't worry about it.  Its just that standards have evolved (by the will of the community and its owners) and there are plenty of questions out there that, while okay when asked, aren't accepted anymore.  Pretty much *any* unacceptable content can be justified by searching previous questions, answers and comments for similar examples that have slipped by.