# Unix.stackexchange.com needs to be added to the mark as offtopic sites list

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, migration

Unix questions are being migrated to http://superuser.com, its ridiculous.

Comment: They said only 5 sites are allowed on that list.

Comment: @YOU OK, if that is so, then the auto-migrate should be probably turned off if at least one of the votes is for a different site, or did not specify the site.

Comment: Why is it ridiculous? Did unix suddenly become off topic for SU?

Comment: @Nicholas What is the point of specialized sites if the generic sites still accept these questions? Plus most of this questions ARE off topic on SU (not just because they are Unix).

Comment: Sounds like you should do some more reading, including right here on meta, about the scope of the general and specialized sites, because you're off track. And please provide links to questions you believe are off topic that have been migrated so that the community and moderators may examine them to see if there is a genuine problem.

Comment: @Nicholas So you are telling me that Unix questions (for example administration questions) are OK on both SU and Unix subsites? Reporting questions seems to be pretty pointless: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87840/any-rules-for-reporting-posts-that-belong-on-forked-sites

Comment: Yes. To use a legal term, there is "overlapping jurisdiction". And I didn't ask you to flag posts, I asked you to provide links so we can all have a look. Incidentally, the views of a single moderator, like the one who responded to your question, may not fully reflect the views of other mods, the community at large, or the SE management, and they may also be highly dependent on context. This question has a very different context from the other one.

Comment: @Nicholas Oh, here it is: http://superuser.com/questions/274857/linux-rights-issue

Comment: Sorry, I do see the problem with that question now, but it's not a particularly good example of a wider problem. That question was very poorly formed and very badly tagged, leading both to the initial migration and my utter bewilderment that you thought it was off-topic. Some questions like that are going to slip through, because they look for all the world like they have nothing to do with programming. By itself, it doesn't really evidence a wider problem.

Comment: @Nicholas And it looks completely off topic to me :-/ I guess I will never understand this on topic / off topic / question moving aspect of StackExchange. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Also, you should, in fact, flag that question, and a moderator will almost certainly deal with it (again, this is a very different context from the question Wil responded to).

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Flag for mod attention in situations like this; give as much detail in the flag as you can.  Bad migrations can be unwound.  Nobody's perfect, remember.