# other SE boards selection list when moving questions

Tags: support, vote-to-close, migration

I wanted to close "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772999/using-at-command-and-bin-sh-script" and suggest move to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ but the other sites choices did not contain the Unix board. How are the choice selection lists for moving questions made? How can I move a question to the actually on-topic board?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88668/unix-stackexchange-com-needs-to-be-added-to-the-mark-as-offtopic-sites-list